# Origin of barricade tape color combinations (allegedly OSHA)

Tags: safety, standards, regulations

Various sources (e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barricade_tape#OSHA_and_ANSI_requirements_for_barricade_tape) and [WorkSafely](http://www.worksafely.com/safety-equipment/barricade-tape.aspx)) claim that the seven color combinations commonly used for barricade tape (a.k.a. caution tape) and safety markings in North America (yellow and black for physical hazards, green and white for first aid supplies, etc.) are specified by the US Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA). OSHA standard [1910.144](https://www.osha.gov/pls/oshaweb/owadisp.show_document?p_table=STANDARDS&p_id=9793) ("Safety color code for marking physical hazards") is often mentioned. However, 1910.144 states only the following regarding color:

- The color red should be used to identify fire protection equipment, sources of danger, and emergency stop controls.
- The color yellow should be used to mark physical hazards.

Are the seven color combinations specified in another OSHA standard? (If so, I haven't been able to find it.) If not, where did they originate?

Comment: Perhaps other countries also specify the color combinations and they are just carried over?

Comment: Kind of ironic how red signals sources of danger while at the same time showing equipment for mitigating dangerous situations